# Issue when creating from scratch toUpperCase function

Tags: javascript

I've been tasking with creating my own version of the `toUpperCase()` fucntion in JavaScript. This is what I have come up with. We were given a tester file and denied access to the source code. My output is as follows:

[image]

```
function stringToUppercase(string) {
    /*
        upper = ['A','B','C', etc...]
        compare lowerY to upperY  get index numbers of lowercase[y] that matches and use those to 
        create matching values at upperCase[y]
        will print newString based on compared upper and lower values
    */

   const upperCase = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
   const lowerCase = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
   const numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
   const specialChar = ['`','~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','_','+','=','{','}','[',']','|',';',':','"','<'];

   let newString = "";

   for (let x = 0; x < string.length; x++){
       for (let y = 0; y < lowerCase.length; y++) {
           if (string[x] === lowerCase[y] || string[x] === upperCase[y]) {
               newString += upperCase[y];
           } else if (string[x] === '\n' || string[x] === '\t' || string[x] === ' '){
               newString += string[x];
           } else if (string[x] === numbers[y]) {
               newString += string[x];
           } else if (string[x] === specialChar[y]) {
               newString += string[x];
           }
       }
   }
   return newString;
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear why it's failing. You may need to check with your instructor. BTW, you don't need to explicitly encode punctuation and whitespace, if the character at a given index isn't in the lower case alphabet all you need to do is append that character to the result string. This is a simple if-else with two branches: one for lower case alpha and another for everything else. Nor is there a need to explicitly code a second loop, arrays have an `.includes` method.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thanks for the input!

Comment: It's failing because you have forgotten the space in special characters. Anyway there are better solutions below leaving out all the special characters. This is beneficial because you don't know all of them. There is also an issue with internationalization. e.g. in German there are also further vocals like ö,ä,ü and your function is not considering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have coded it up again, but this time following your requirements:

```
function stringToUppercase(string) {
    const lowerCase = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    const upperCase = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var newString = "";

    outer:
    for (var char = 0; char < string.length; char ++) {
        for (var letter = 0; letter < lowerCase.length; letter ++) {
            if (string[char] == lowerCase[letter]) {
                newString += upperCase[letter];
                continue outer;
            }
        }

        newString += string[char];
    }
    return newString;
}
```

Comment: This works! Could you provide some documentation on how "outer:" works.

Comment: Sure. >>> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_continue.asp
It is explained towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded up a much more efficient 'stringToUppercase' function for you:

```
function stringToUppercase(string) {
    const lowerCase = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    const upperCase = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var newString = string;

    for (var char = 0; char < lowerCase.length; char += 1) {
        for (var x = 0; x < string.split(lowerCase[char]).length; x += 1) {
            newString = newString.replace(lowerCase[char], upperCase[char]);
        }
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Hi Prime, Unfortunately we are not allowed to use any built in functions other than .length. I should've included this in my original post.

Comment: Ah I see! I will try something else then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably the most efficient solution.

```js
function stringToUppercase(str) {
    let out = "";
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (charCode >= 0x61 && charCode <= 0x7A)
            out += String.fromCharCode(charCode - 0x20);
        else
            out += str[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

However, since you can't use built-in functions:

```js
function stringToUppercase(string) {
    const caseMap = {"a":"A", "b":"B", "c":"C", "d":"D", "e":"E", "f":"F", "g":"G", "h":"H", "i":"I", "j":"J", "k":"K", "l":"L", "m":"M", "n":"N", "o":"O", "p":"P", "q":"Q", "r":"R", "s":"S", "t":"T", "u":"U", "v":"V", "w":"W", "x":"X", "y":"Y", "z":"Z"}
    var newString = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
        const char = string[i];
        if (char in caseMap)
            newString += caseMap[char];
        else
            newString += char;
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks D. These are both helpful as well. The caseMap is a very interesting way of doing it. I will definitely have to read up more on this!